# How many endings are there to original The Stanley Parable (2011)?

Tags: the-stanley-parable-2011

I found six, which also are shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gblvOhnv2k0). Are there any endings left in the original mod version?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You got them all. There are 6 endings in total, as [verified by the author](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/j8b64/after_2_years_ive_finished_my_game_its_some_sort/c2a02h9?context=1). Here's a branching graph:

> [image: branching graph]

Comment: The branching graph (almost spoiler-free): http://i.imgur.com/W3KCU.png (I found this graph from the [reddit thread linked in this answer](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/j8b64/after_2_years_ive_finished_my_game_its_some_sort/c2a3ozo))

Answer (score 0):

Well, there a bug-ending where you press a button in the elevator and then leave before it  up/down but other than that, no there is not another ending.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more, you can get stuck in the metal thingy after you break free from the death sentence and the girly voice is leading you around.

Comment: So is that a bug or a real ending?

Comment: Why the downvote? I can confirm that's a real ending.

Comment: @Septagram Perhaps you can explain how this ending goes in a way that doesn't make it sound like a bug?

Comment: Well, the girly voice says a few things and then you go into that big museum place. After you are done with it, you are crushed, and there is blackness and (AFAIK) there's nothing after that: no menu and absolutely nothing to do. While the game doesn't *technically* end, the museum does look like a valid ending to me.

Comment: Oh, the question is only about the original mod version :( What happens in the original version there?

Answer (score -1):

I got stuck on the floor of the **** ******* ****** (the room with the walkways that rise up and the hundreds of screens, don't want to spoil it entirely!)

On the first table, climb up onto the chair and then jump off into the darkness. I remained there forever...

Comment: Original Stanley Parable, or the one just released on Steam?

Answer (score -1):

Well there are numerous different endings in the Stanley Parable game.

1. You follow all the directions and you escape from the hell hole job after discovering that EVERYONE, even YOU are being controlled by your boss.
2. You disobey EVERYTHING the British VoiceOver told you and go through many different doors but change your mind to listen to him FINALLY at the elevator and press the up button. You are then led to your death… TWICE.
3. You still ignore the Voice and go to a Random place where there is no story line for you. Forcing you to stroll through the wasteland for all eternity.
4. You follow His directions again and you reach a machine. You choose to power up the machine which Pisses off the Voice and he makes the machine explode. You Die…
5. (Again) You follow the voice up until you reach a stairwell. You go downstairs instead of upstairs. That's where you realized everything isn't real it's all make believe. You suffer from a mental breakdown and Die, the view of your body zooming out.