# How many endings are in the 2013 edition of The Stanley Parable?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

There's already [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28024/how-many-endings-are-there-to-the-stanley-parable) asking this for the original *Stanley Parable* game. But now that there is a new, shiny version of the game on Steam, how many endings does it have? And which endings are "new" to the new game?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's start this off with the endings I've already found.  Spoilers on, of course.

Starting with:

**The Reluctant Ending**

> Don't leave your room at all, just close your door at the start of the game.  You'll probably get this ending by  accident if you pause the game and click back in at some point.  Your reward is  insecurity in your own actions.

**The Agreeable Ending**

> The ending that the narrator 'intended' you to have.  Simply do everything you are  told.  Go through the left door, ascend the stairs, enter the secret room, ignore the exit, and turn off the machine.  Your reward is the outdoors, and an actual achievement.

**The Insanity Ending**

> Take the door on the left, but walk down the stairs instead of up.  Your reward is your own dementia.

**The Confusion Ending**

> My personal favorite ending so far.  Take the door on the right, then take the first door on your left, then take the lift down.  Your reward is a very long, very confusing ending that at least has the decency to name itself.

**The Game Ending**

> You just lost it.  Take the door on the right, go straight forward, ride the lift, and then jump off onto the catwalk below. Take the blue door 3 times. Your reward is incredibly obvious parody.

**The Overeager Ending**

> Oops.  Take the door on the right, go straight forward, and jump into the pit.  Your reward is a quick but painful death. There is a second version of narration to go with this if you step onto the platform and off again, letting it go on without you.

**The Life Ending**

> Take the door on the right, go straight forward, ride the lift up without falling, then answer the phone.  Your reward is being trapped in a mundane office job.

**The Real Person Ending**

> Take the door on the right, go straight forward, ride the lift up without falling, then disconnect the phone.  Your reward is being a real person!

So far, I count eight endings, with at least two being like or very similar to the endings from the original game.

There is a list of endings being written on the Steam Forums that is mostly complete.  You can find it [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=186748414#160736).

Comment: How long do you have to wait for the Reluctant ending? If I close the door nothing happens.

Comment: @MarkKramer It should happen immediately, but you need to stay inside your room to trigger it.  I'll add this to my answer since I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Does it have to be at the very beginning of the game? I understood that you had to stay in the room, I restarted and closed the door and nothing happened.

Comment: @MarkKramer I'm not sure what problem you might be having then.  Are you standing in the room you start in, not moving at all in any direction, closing the door, and waiting for dialogue to begin?  Those should be the only steps you need, and if you're not getting the ending that way, I suggest you make a new Question to answer this peculiar problem.

Comment: I got it, the answer was that you have to do it at the VERY beginning, you can't just start again and do it.

Answer (score 46):

Here is a chart summarizing most of the endings discovered so far (mouse-over to view it):

> [image: Endings Chart]

Comment: What does ">3rd" mean, coming off of the boss node in the lower-left?

Comment: @Tacroy To avoid spoilers for others, I'll just say: see the answer posted by Telespentry for more info about the ending you are interested.

Comment: Maybe add a key that explains red circles as endings and orange as events that do not end the game.

Comment: I'm really wondering about the bomb ending. I somehow managed to open the doors in the room with many buttons, but they closed when I approached. Perhaps there is a way to escape.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I think the door will just open after a while. There most likely won't be a way to solve the puzzle, because there wasn't a way in the 2011 version (and it was confirmed by devs).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be The door opens by itself, it had nothing to do with you pressing buttons. For me the door was just open when I came back from the control panel.

Comment: Did you create this chart yourself, or was it from somewhere else?

Answer (score 29):

In addition to the 8 endings Zibbobz's listed there are:

**The Space Ending**

> Go through the right door, straight ahead, and onto the cargo lift. Jump off the lift and onto the catwalk. Go through the red door...

In the mod, this is where the 'life' ending goes, but that's gone elsewhere and this is completely different.

**The Escape Pod Ending**

> Follow the directions until you get to the Boss's room. Walk through the double doors, and then back out as the game attempts to close them on you. Go back toward your office, and the room next to yours will now have an open door...

Nothing similar is in the mod.

**The Heaven Ending**

> Follow the narrator's instructions, but look at each computer you pass by on the way. One of them will say 'awaiting input'. Click it, and it'll switch to 'input received'. Go to the menu and select 'begin the game again', and repeat these steps 4 more times...

Nothing similar is in the mod.

**The Out-of-bounds Ending**

> Run toward the chair to climb up this desk. 
>  [image: Where to find the out-of-bounds ending]
>  Crawl over to the other side of the divider and hop out the window. You may at first think you've broken the map, but it's all part of the game...

Nothing similar is in the mod.

**The Museum Ending**

> Follow the Narrator's instructions until you reach a path labelled 'escape'. Take this path instead of entering the Mind Control Facility.

This is analogous to the 'down the elevator' path in the original, but is greatly expanded upon.

**The Serious Room**

> Attempt to cheat by adding -console to the launch parameters and type `sv_cheats 1`

Nothing similar is in the mod.

There's also, arguably, **The Whiteboard Ending** and the **Broom Closet Ending**, but these don't actually end the game.

Comment: Not familiar with the Whiteboard one...

Comment: Some of these are incredible. How did people find these so quickly?

Comment: Patience, perseverance, and lots and lots of procrastination of our own lives.

Comment: How do I start the steam game with "-console" as an argument? When I look at the shortcut, it's some kind of webdocument ... is the an executable somewhere that I have to call?

Comment: @Hinek Right-click on your game in steam, and chose "properites", which allows you to add a source command for game startup.

Answer (score 14):

**Transcendence**

> As The Game ending (door on the right, go straight, jump off the platform, blue door three times), but play the Narrator's "baby crawling into fire" game for four hours, as the Narrator says. Note that after an hour or two, the Narrator will add in his "puppy falling into a pool of piranhas" game. You must play both games simultaneously. After four hours, you will get this ending. If you don't want to go through all that, [here's a video of what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jsm0vnB3Q2Y).

Comment: Wow, that's some dedication...

Comment: Respect! 4 hours for that.. wow!

Answer (score 5):

Two sort of unofficial endings (endings that do not result in the game resetting itself):

The whiteboard ending

> Sometimes when you restart, you'll be in a grayer office. When you leave your office there will be about 8 doors or so and you would normally progress by walking around a section of filing cabinets. If you try opening some of these doors, one of them will open and will be a small room that only has a whiteboard and on it in red marker it'll say "the whiteboard ending".

The broom closet ending:

> When on your way up to the boss's office (before you go up the stairs) you'll find a door labeled "Broom Closet". Go inside and wait.  After the dialog finishes, exit the broom closet, then go back in.
>
>  After this, the next time you play, the broom closet will be locked up.  Not so much an ending as it is an easter-egg.

Comment: As long as we're mentioning non-ending easter eggs, here's another one:  If you enter the code in the boss' room (`2845`) before the narrator is done talking, you'll get some funny new dialog.  The next time you enter that room, the door will already be open and the narrator will only say *"Just go."*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it's not necessarily the next time you enter the room. These events seem to be random to some extent.

Comment: Equally interesting is that you can enter the code from the old game, 1947, the narrator will act as if you've entered the code correctly, but the door won't open.  Though this doesn't 'end' the game, since if you have good aim you can still enter the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

**The "Final Boss" Ending**

> Play through the game doing exactly as your told except on the last choice, turn the machine "on" instead of "off". A "Final Boss" fight will ensue where you have to push certain buttons to defeat the Narrator or do nothing and succumb to a nuclear explosion.

Comment: Any description on how to stop the bomb?

Comment: There most likely won't be a way to stop the bomb because there wasn't a way in the 2011 version (and it was confirmed by devs).

Answer (score 1):

I have another.

**The Elevator Simulator**

> Follow the narrator until the top of the stairs. Instead of going left into your boss's office, go into the doors on the right and go in the elevator. If you press up or down, nothing happens other than the elevator shaking and playing music.

**Note:** This "ending" is only attainable if you go through the Escape Pod ending. The next time you go to the boss's area, you can go in both the executive bathroom and room on the right.

**Counter-Note** The "ending" is randomly attainable btw.  Most of the time on your third time to the boss's office.

Comment: I would disagree that this is actually an ending, as the game does not in fact end nor does it in any way indicate that this might be some sort of an ending.

Comment: It's also not a requirement to have achieved the escape pod ending before you can do this - I haven't had that ending yet, but I have been in the elevator that goes nowhere.