# What is the code for the mind control room in The Stanley Parable?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

Is there a code at the end when you press "On" instead of "Off". What is it also?

Answer (score 13):

As you can see in [this ending chart](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/136418/2578), hitting `on` only has one possible outcome - your death.  There is no code to stop it.

It was the same way in the original mod.  This also fits in with the game's theme of breaking the rules of traditional games.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard based on forum posts and my own experience there is no code it's all just useless time wasters.

I've tried multiple combinations of the 1-5 buttons with no success.